# How to acces rows in the ndarray with indices stored in the other array?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, multidimensional-array

Let's say I've got 1 2D array 1000x20:

```
X = np.random.randint(0,5001,size=(1000,20))
```

And second 1D array with 1000 random numbers:

```
row_indices = np.random.permutation(X.shape[0])
```

I'd like to access only X rows from row_indices[0:600], row_indices[600:800] and row_indices[800:1000]. What's the best approach?

Comment: `y1 = X[row_indices[:600]]; y2 = X[row_indices[600:800]]; y3 = X[row_indices[800:]]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass a (sliced) version of `row_indices` as subscript to `X` to obtain the corresponding rows.

So we can make three variables `y1`, `y2` and `y3` that each obtain their share of `X` with:

```
X = np.random.randint(0,5001,size=(1000,20))
row_indices = np.random.permutation(X.shape[0])

y1 = X[row_indices[0:600]]
y2 = X[row_indices[600:800]]
y3 = X[row_indices[800:1000]]
```

Here `y1` is thus a *600×20* matrix that contains the rows from `X` with the indices of `row_indices` for the first 600 indices, and so on.